# Need to create thumbnail from user submitted url like reddit/facebook

Tags: python, django, image

I am pretty new to Django so I am creating a project to learn more about how it works. Right now I have a model that contains a URL field. I want to automatically generate a thumbnail from this url field by taking an appropriate image from the webite like facebook or reddit does. I'm guessing that I should store this image in an image field. What would be a good way to select an ideal image from the website and how can I accomplish this?

EDIT- I'm trying to take actual images from the website rather than a picture of the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to parse the html content for img src urls with something like lxml or BeautifulSoup. Then, you can feed one of those img src urls into sorl-thumbnail or easy-thumbnails as Edmon suggests.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Generating the thumbnail isn't the issue. That's easy. The hard part is determining which image on the page is the most "appropriate". An answer like scytale's is a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 4):

First off you can check if the site uses any Facebook [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) tags - namely `<meta property="og:image" content="http://..."/>`.

Answer (score 1):

One option, which is not specific to Django, is to take a snapshot of a page using [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/)
and then use Sorl or Easy Thumbnails to generate image url.

Sorl - https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail

Easy Thumbnails - https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails

Comment: I'm trying to take actual images from the website rather than a picture of the website